# in asp.net can we give same name to session variable and cache variable

Tags: asp.net, session, variables

in asp.net can we give same name to session variable and cache variable
like

`session["lookup"] = "a"; cache["lookup"] = "A123";` ?

will it not get clashed at the access point in any page ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Cache collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)?

If so, this is not the same collection as the Session. The session is an application wide user specific collection where the Cache is application wide but not user specific. Its also not the same object.

From msdn:

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active.

I should also warn that the cache collection is a global object for all the users, and therefore I think that user specific information should be avoided.

Best practices and use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx